# Can all elements be found in our body?

Tags: human-biology

There are many Natural occurring atomic elements.
Can they all be found in the human body?
Is our system capable of letting them all in?
Are they all contained in our food?

Three in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://www.lenntech.com/periodic-chart-elements/human-body.htmlanguage, you find 118 elements sorted by the percent of appearance in the human body, starting with oxygen (65%) down to "very low traces of lead". There are a lot of elements which can't be found, including Osmium.

You can sort the table by other orders like name, symbol, mass, and others.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is more of a chemistry question than a biology question? Our body doesn't make use of all elements, as far as we know, (somewhere between 20 and 29 elements have been suggested to have some use by mammals) but it probably contains every naturally occurring element in some tiny concentration, if you measure with sufficient sensitivity. Barring obviously those which are extremely rare or unstable.

Proving a negative is very difficult - I don't know how you could say with confidence - "there are zero atoms of osmium in this body".

Comment: This question is about biology. It concerns living beings. Bio. -1